# prove the following inequality using am gm hm or weirstrass etc

Tags: inequality, a.m.-g.m.-inequality, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

For $a_0,a_1,a_2,......,a_n \in R, \,\, a_0<a_1<a_2<....<a_n$ show that
$$ \frac n{a_1-a_0}+\frac {n-1}{a_2-a_1}+....+\frac 1{a_n-a_{n-1}} \ge \sum_{k=1}^n \frac {k^2}{a_k} $$
i recently studied inequalities am gm hm , tchebychev, weirstrass, cauchy schwarz.
i am trying to solve some questions i don't know how to start on this one can someone please help me on this.

Comment: Where can i find $$a_0$$?

Comment: Dr. Sonnhard Graubner corrected it

Comment: @ Michael Rozenberg  why are we considering that?

Comment: For $a_1\rightarrow0^+$ the right side is closed to $+\infty$.

Comment: can you explain further @Michael Rozenberg

Comment: It says that your inequality is wrong. Maybe you need to add $a_0>0$?

Comment: @Michael Rozenberg we can assume a_0>0 , then what can we do further

Comment: @Michael Rozenberg we can assume things in the question .. i tried applying weierstrass inequality but i can not reach to any conclusion

Comment: Duplicate of [Show this inequality $\frac{n}{a_1 - a_0} + \frac{n - 1}{a_2 - a_1} + \cdots + \frac{1}{a_n - a_{n-1}} \ge \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{k^2}{a_k}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3157060/show-this-inequality-fracna-1-a-0-fracn-1a-2-a-1-cdots) (without restrictions on $a_0$ the inequality is wrong).